# Why "Get-Content" is not refreshing contents live?

Tags: windows, powershell, tail

I have a logfile and used the command `Get-Content myLog.log –Wait` to show the contents of this file, just like with the linux equivalent `tail`.

I noticed that the content is not updated live like I know it from `tail`. The content is only refreshed after a specific interval. How can I change the interval, I think I have to pass an argument for `Wait` so that it knows how long to wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet doesn't expose a property nor a function to set the refresh intervall. You probably have to do it yourself:

```
$linesPrinted = 0;

while ($true) 
{ 
    $content = Get-Content myLog.log
    $currentLineCount = $content | Measure-Object -Line | select -expand Lines

    if ($currentLineCount -gt $linesPrinted)
    {
        $content[$linesPrinted .. $currentLineCount]
        $linesPrinted = $currentLineCount
    }


    Sleep -Milliseconds 100 
}
```

Comment: In which format do i have to save this script to make it executable ?

Comment: To test your scripts, you should start `Powershell_ISE` (best as Admin). Copy & Paste the script to the `Script Pane` and press `F5` to execute it. Later, you can save the script as a `ps1` file and execute it using powershell.

Comment: Thx, but your code does not work as expected, it always loads the file completly from the start.

Comment: Yes it works perfect now :) Thx! Is it possible to create a module with your code so we can use it like this: `wintail path/to/file` ?